# How I can create a dataframe using Function from vectors?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, rstudio

I'm trying to create a Data Frame using Function. This function is based on three different vectors (Tol, Bzn, mXyl) related to a 101 wavelengths of absorbance. I want to multiply by different concentrations and store it in a dataframe as a result.

I've created a simply code (I know I could make that with other more polite functions but I'm bit principiant in R) that creates 27 rows of different combinations between concentrations for each vector. So, this 27 rows have to be the dataframe rows, and each column would have to be each wavelength stored in the vectors. (Wavelengths are the Variables)

as a example of structure of Tol vector (Bzn and mXyl are similar):

```
str(Tol)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  101 variables:

$ nm200: num 8.13

$ nm201: num 8.3

$ nm202: num 8.47

$ nm203: num 8.69

$ nm204: num 8.91
```

(...) There are 200 to 300 wavelengths. You can visualyze it!

```
$ nm294: num 0

$ nm295: num 0

$ nm296: num 0

$ nm297: num 0

$ nm298: num 0
```

And my little (and first) function created using R:

```
Con1 = 1

Con2 = 2

Con3 = 3

mat_cont <- function(Tol, Bzn, mXyl,Con1,Con2, Con3){

n1  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  0   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0   * (mXyl*Con3)

n2  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  0   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0.5 * (mXyl*Con3)

n3  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  0   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  1   * (mXyl*Con3)

n4  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  0.5 * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0   * (mXyl*Con3)

n5  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  1   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0   * (mXyl*Con3)

n6  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  0.5 * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0.5 * (mXyl*Con3)

n7  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  0.5 * (Bzn*Con2)  +  1   * (mXyl*Con3)

n8  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  1   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0.5 * (mXyl*Con3)

n9  <-  0    * (Tol*Con1) +  1   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  1   * (mXyl*Con3)

n10 <-  0.5  * (Tol*Con1) +  0   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0   * (mXyl*Con3)

(...)

n25 <-  1    * (Tol*Con1) +  0.5 * (Bzn*Con2)  +  1   * (mXyl*Con3)

n26 <-  1    * (Tol*Con1) +  1   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  0.5 * (mXyl*Con3)

n27 <-  1    * (Tol*Con1) +  1   * (Bzn*Con2)  +  1   * (mXyl*Con3)

result <- (data.frame(??????)


return(result)

}
```

I would want to have a dataframe like that, with the name of the columns as a nm200, nm201, nm202, nm203...:

```
n1   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)

n2   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)

n3   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)

n4   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)

n5   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)

(...)

n26   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)

n27   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6   val7   val8   val9 (...)
```

Thank you very much for your incomputable help!

Comment: write data.frame(n1,n2, ... n26, n27) and your vectors should become a data.frame

Comment: I just tried that answer. The result is a data frame with 1 row and 2700 columns...

Comment: can you give us some data to work with please?

Comment: @user1945827 I don't know how I can merge the vectors of my work

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do.  As background, I think that you have three different solutions ... toluene, benzene and meta-xylene.  Presumably you've ran some sort of spectroscopy (uv?) to give a vector of absorbance values.  And then what ...?

Comment: I wonder if you need to make a data.frame from your three vectors and use the lapply function to get your desired result but I'm still guessing because I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, it's something like you said. I'm trying to do an virtual experimentation, where every level I design is a different relation between these contaminants. With a controled concentration of contaminants (Con1, Con2 and Con3) we suppose different cases (or levels). The first case (n1) only water, in the second case (n2) only a half of controled concentration of mXyl, in the third case (n3) all controled concetration of mXyl, etc. I would want to create a data frame with my new vectors (n1,n2,...,n27) where will be the different level concentrations ready to sum to other dataframes

Comment: So, can you give us a very small subset of your data, perhaps nm200 to nm210 for each of your three solutions?  With this we can plug it into your function and see what we do (and don't) get out of it.